# Tail light doesn't work, when I turn on the headlight

Tags: honda, civic, wiring, fuse, tail-lights

I have a 2007 Honda Civic with over 200k miles. When I turn on the headlight, tail lights don't turn on. Turn signal light works fine, brake light works fine and reverse light works fine as well. I don't understand why the tail lights won't turn on. What can possibly cause this problem?

Comment: A faulty switch possibly...

Comment: Or a wiring fault in the + wire that carries taillight current from the dash/fuse area back to the rear end of the car.

Comment: Have you checked the fuses and relays?

Comment: Are the front marker lights working? Check fuse 15